# Scroll con botones en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Estoy intentando hacer una serie de scrolls en horizontal que se desplacen con dos botones en javascript y de momento esto es lo que tengo, a ver si podéis ayudarme. He hecho el código así un poco a groso modo.

Es decir, imaginaros una lista horizontal con imagenes, y cada vez que le dáis a un botón se desplazan de tres en tres, algo así. En el medio están los divs y a los laterales, de forma externa al div del medio, los botones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML

```
<div class="flechaizquierda">
<a id='izquierda'><img src='izquierda.png'></a>
</div>

<div id="contenedor">
<div id="cajauno">
<img class="imagen">
<div class="texto">
<h5>Texto</h5>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cajados">
<img class="imagen">
<div class="texto">
<h5>Texto</h5>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cajatres">
<img class="imagen">
<div class="texto">
<h5>Texto</h5>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cajacuatro">
<img class="imagen">
<div class="texto">
<h5>Texto</h5>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cajacinco">
<img class="imagen">
<div class="texto">
<h5>Texto</h5>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flechaderecha">
<a id='derecha'><img src='derecha.png'></a>
</div>

</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#izquierda').toggle(
        function(){
            $("#contenedorreco").animate({"left": "1500px"}, "slow");
        }, function(){
            $(".#contenedorreco").animate({"left": "-1500px"}, "slow");
        }
    );
});
$(function(){
    $('#derecha').toggle(
        function(){
            $("#contenedorreco").animate({"right": "1500px"}, "slow");
        }, function(){
            $(".#contenedorreco").animate({"right": "-1500px"}, "slow");
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Agradecería que pudierais ayudarme porque estoy desesperado.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Crear un slider con valores recogidos de una API PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212935/crear-un-slider-con-valores-recogidos-de-una-api-php)

Comment: Lo que estás intentando hacer es un carrusel ( o carousel en inglés ). Es importante tener en cuenta que ya existen librerías que te facilitan crear este tipo de componente.